# notepad++ find and replace

Tags: notepad++

I'm trying to find and replace across multiple files. I'm changing locations of header files in c codes, so for example I'd like to change ti/xdais/[wildcard].h with xdm/ti/xdais/[wildcard].h

I'd like to find

```
ti/xdais
```

and replace with

```
xdm/ti/xdais
```

If I just do a find all, it works as expected and finds all references. But when I try and do a find and replace it doesn't work. Says nothing found. ANy ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out. The files I attempting to replace in were write-protected. Notepad++ Gave no indication of this so it took me a little while to realize it.